# Video is not pausing when exits on viewport using brightcove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, brightcove

I'm trying play multiple brightcove videos on page and same as when video is exits browser viewport i would like to stop playing which one is exits on viewport. As of now, If the page have multiple videos on page its playing when visible on viewport but the problem is its not stop playing when exits on viewport.

Please suggest where i made mistake.

```
$(currentVideo).each(function(){
    if(viewPort !== false) {
        videojs('#'+ currentVideo).ready(function() {
            var myPlayer = this;
            window.onscroll = checkIfVideoInView();
            function checkIfVideoInView() {
                if (isScrolledIntoView('#'+ currentVideo)) {
                    console.log('play started');
                    myPlayer.play();
                } else {
                    console.log('play stopped');
                    myPlayer.pause();
                }
            }

            checkIfVideoInView();

            function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
                var docViewTop      = $(window).scrollTop();
                var docViewBottom   = docViewTop + $(window).height();
                var elemTop         = $(elem).offset().top;
                var elemBottom      = elemTop + $(elem).outerHeight();
                return (
                    elemBottom > docViewTop &&
                    elemTop < docViewBottom
                );
            }
        });
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is based on or similar to Brigthcove's own [Scrolling Player View plugin](https://github.com/BrightcoveLearning/18202-scrolling-player-view/blob/master/plugin/scroll-into-view.js).  The only differences I see are:

Instead of `var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).outerHeight();` their plugin uses:
`var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();`

And in their return, they are also checking that the bottom is less than or equal to the doc view bottom and top greater than doc view top as such:

```
return (
  elemBottom >= docViewTop &&
  elemTop <= docViewBottom &&
  elemBottom <= docViewBottom &&
  elemTop >= docViewTop
);
```

Hope this helps!
-Michael